# Why Directory.GetDirectories output is different from dir with /a:d?

Tags: c#, windows-10

I tried to write a method to enumerate all directories recursively, and then compared its result with dir command result. It appears that some directories are returned by dir and ignored by GetDirectories, for example:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Windows\System32\spp")
```

returns an array with a single element - `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\spp\\tokens"`
and

```
dir "C:\Windows\System32\spp" /b /a:d
```

returns three directories:

```
plugin-manifests-signed
store
tokens
```

Another example is the C:\Windows\System32\spool directory, it is not listed in `Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Windows\System32")` but appears in `dir "C:\Windows\System32" /b /a:d`, as well as some other directories under `C:\Windows\System32`

Vice versa, there are directories not visible in explorer and not listed in dir output, although returned by GetDirectories, in my case it was C:\Windows\System32\InstallShield and its subdirectories.

 Not that I want to manipulate those directories, but it made me curious, what is so special about C:\Windows\System32\InstallShield, C:\Windows\System32\spp subdiresctories and others that they are visible in one way and not in another.

I'm using C# 6.0 and Windows 10 version 1803

Comment: Maybe you lack elevation and thus run into Virtualsiation? https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/article.php/c15455/Tip-To-Disable-Virtualization.htm it is also possible the compiler is going out of it's way to protect your programm directory from bugging applications during development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the build your application is set to and its going into the SYSWOW folder instead

You could try replacing that with SYSnative in your path - folder doesnt exist but it seems to work.

I've ran into the same problem trying to enumerate registry keys

Comment: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector

Comment: very helpful links

Comment: Indeed, it is amazing that the directories are 99% similar